# Merging tree conflict on XCode

Tags: xcode, git, merge, conflict

I'm coding on XCode 8.2.1 and I get the following error when I try to merge two branches:

[image]

Does anyone know why is it happening? And how could it be solved?

pd: Tried to add "xcschememanagement.plist" to .gitignore, but not solved

Thank you!